# Get the hostname inside getStaticProps

Tags: javascript, next.js

Is it possible to get the hostname inside `getStaticProps`?

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  // get the hostname 
  const hostname = ?????
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to get the hostname inside `getStaticProps` as the props generated there are static and do not contain information on the request in any way. To get the hostname, you will have to use `getServerSideProps` or get the hostname on the client side in the page's component. Here is an example of getting the hostname in `getServerSideProps`:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<{ host: string; }> = async (context) => {
  return {
    props: { host: context.req.headers.host || null }
  };
};
```

Here is an example of getting the hostname on the client side component using `Location`:

```
function Home() {
  // window can be undefined when static generated, however it will be updated when the page is hydrated
  const hostname = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.location.hostname : '';
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score -1):

create function :

```
export const hostname = "https://urldomain.com"
```

and import everywhere

```
import {hostname} from "./hostname";

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
 // get the hostname 
console.log(hostname)
}
```

Comment: And if i want to get it from route and not as static value?

Comment: @pellebyshellygafni That's not possible inside `getStaticProps`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73346445/1870780.

Comment: i use that in  getServerSideProps for fetch! are you sure its not possible inside getStaticProps ? @juliomalves

Comment: @H9ee To be clear: your solution is fine, my comment was to answer @pellebyshellygafni question. But to re-iterate, it's not possible to get the hostname inside `getStaticProps` dynamically because `getStaticProps` does not contain any information about the request. Unlike `getServerSideProps` that runs on each request to the page, `getStaticProps` runs once, on the server at _build_ time.

Comment: I didn't have many projects in getStaticProps! So it was interesting, thank you @juliomalves